# Why don't builtins or classes without __hash__ explicitly defined use __hash__ in dicts?

Tags: python

For example:

```
import cProfile
cProfile.run('print(len({i:i for i in range(-10, 10)}))') # 20; no hash shown
```

And:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

cProfile.run('print(len({Test(i):i for i in range(-10, 10)}))') # 20; init, no hash
```

But:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.i

cProfile.run('print(len({Test(i):i for i in range(-10, 10)}))') # 20; init and hash
```

For the former two, `cProfile` shows nothing to indicate that the `dict` is `hash`ing them. However, it must be comparing keys in some way, and I don't know how to resolve that contradiction. How do Python dicts know how to store objects for the former two without `hash`ing them?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. They do hash the values.

Comment: But `__hash__` isn't shown in the profile. If they do hash the value, why isn't it there?

Comment: `if not hasattr(obj, '__hash__')`, the hash defaults to `id(obj)`.

Comment: I guess I should backpedal a bit. For the former two, `cProfile` shows nothing to indicate that the `dict` is `hash`ing them. However, it must be comparing keys in some way, and I don't know how to resolve that contradiction. --- Added that to the question.

Comment: The profiler is only going to show a call to `__hash__()` for objects that actually implement such a method *in Python*.  In your first two examples, the details of hashing are contained entirely within the underlying C implementation of the objects; there is no Python call involved for the profiler to see.